# Windows Update Failure

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-update

When I start my computer (Windows 7 Pro 32-bit) I get the following message:

> Configuring Windows Updates
>
> 0% Complete
>
> Do not turn of your computer

This stays on the screen for about 5 minutes, then it says

> Failure to configure Windows updates.
>
> Reverting changes .

And then boots normally.

This only started happening a few days ago, and as far as I am aware, I haven't changed anything significantly, I'm assuming it is because of a Windows Update that it installed itself.

Anyone know how I can get rid of this?

Comment: What's the hexa error number?

Comment: It doesn't give one, all it says is what I posted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem this morning 64-bit win7. I usually choose the option for windows to update itself when I shut down the computer.

To try to get around the problem I started Windows Update manually. Told it to install the updates and then rebooted when it asked to.

Next upstart was normal and the problem was gone.

Comment: And if this doesn't work, manually running Windows Update will at least tell you WHICH update is failing.

Comment: Thanks Nifle and Velociraptors, doing a manual Windows Update fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem happened to me yesterday on my Win7 64-bit laptop. I was able to (finally) update successfully when I disconnected the Dell external monitor. From what I have gathered online this may have to do with hardware, so I'd try disconnecting all external hardwares, remove all memories cards and give it another shot.

[Update] It happened to me again, and unplugging the ext. monitor didn't work this time. I went into windows update and updated the packages manually rather than waiting for them to install during shutdown, and I was able to install reboot successfully.

Comment: Ah, that's quite possible, seeing as I had an external monitor also when I had the problem.