# Windows 7 updates. For five days in a row

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Since the last five days, a PC with Windows 7 shows the updates screen when booting and when switching off, usually for about 5-10 minutes.

I can understand this when an update occurs, but why does it keeps doing this for at least five continuous days?

What's wrong, this is not my own PC, I'm used to to my *beloved* XP, so I can't give a proper reply to who is asking me "to do something" :-)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's different updates that are being installed? It could be that an automatic update fails and the computer keeps trying to install it. ([this has happened before](https://superuser.com/questions/194522/windows-update-failure/194544#194544))

Try telling the user to manually start the update and see if this fixes the problem.

Comment: Looking at the logs I've seen a lot of failures. Now I've started the manual update, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, doing the updates manually worked, but I still don't know why the automatic updates failed.

Comment: @UVL - Me neither, google turned up nothing when I looked. If you should stumble across the reason later you can always post it as a comment here, or perhaps as a separate answer.